# In the given code, how can I ask Mathematica to replace the obtained points in function $g$ and plot it?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, replacement

I obtain a set of points which are the solutions of `f[b, c, d] == 0` by this code

```
f[b_, c_, d_] = -11 c^4 - 4 c^2 b + (7 + b) c + 8 (c + d/9) d^3;

points = N[{b, c, d} /. FindInstance[f[b, c, d] == 0 && -(1/2) < b < 0  && -1/2 < c < 0 &&   0 < d < 6, {b, c, d}, 3]]

(*  {{-0.472637, -0.344828, 3.17978}, {-0.313433, -0.44335,  4.04363}, {-0.0447761, -0.216749, 2.12847}} *)
```

**Question.** Then, I want to plot another function `g` at those obtained points. In the code below, I substituted the points manually, how can I ask Mathematica to do this replacement by a code (I mean without putting them by hand)?

```
g = (-7 b^2)/(c + 2  d)^6;

p1 = Plot[g /. {b -> -0.472636815920398` , c -> -0.3448275862068966`, d ->3.179783265064255` }, {t, 0, 3}];

p2 = Plot[g /.{b -> -0.31343283582089554`, c-> -0.4433497536945813`, d -> 4.043627580473731` }, {t, 0, 3}];

p3 = Plot[g /. {b -> -0.04477611940298507`, c -> -0.21674876847290642`, d ->2.1284701801564667`}, {t, 0, 3}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Map[(-7 b^2)/(c + 2 d)^6 /. {b -> #[[1]], c -> #[[2]],d -> #[[3]]} &, points]
(*{-0.0000330257, -3.44743*10^-6, -3.22685*10^-6}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of the `FindInstance` is already a list of rules:

```
solns = FindInstance[f[b, c, d] == 0 && -(1/2) < b < 0 && -1/2 < c < 0 && 0 < d < 6, {b, c, d}, 3];
N[solns]
(* {{b -> -0.472637, c -> -0.344828, d -> 3.17978}, 
    {b -> -0.313433, c -> -0.44335, d -> 4.04363}, 
    {b -> -0.0447761, c -> -0.216749, d -> 2.12847}} *)
```

So you can use that to do your replacements:

```
g /. solns // N
(* {-0.00003302573111062388, -3.4474279611533065*^-6, 3.2268529976080994*^-6} *)
```

You can access them one at a time:

```
g /. solns[[1]] // N
(* -0.00003302573111062388 *)
```

Alternatively, you could define a related function:

```
g2[b_, c_, d_] := Evaluate[g];

g2 @@@ points
(* {-0.00003302573111062388, -3.4474279611533065*^-6, -3.2268529976080994*^-6} *)
```

This depends on the order of the arguments, so, another option would be to build a function based on your knowledge of the position of each argument you used to create `points`:

```
g3 = (-7 #[[1]]^2)/(#[[2]] + 2 #[[3]])^6 &;

g3 /@ points
(* {-0.00003302573111062388, -3.4474279611533065*^-6, -3.2268529976080994*^-6} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[b_, c_, d_] = -11  c^4 - 4  c^2  b + (7 + b)  c + 8  (c + d/9)  d^3;

n = 750;

solns = FindInstance[
   f[b, c, d] == 0 && -(1/2) < b < 0 && -1/2 < c < 0 && 0 < d < 6, {b,
     c, d}, n];

g = (-7  b^2)/(c + 2   d)^6 /. solns;

#[g // N] & /@ {Min, Mean, Median, Max, StandardDeviation}

(* {-3.40868, -0.0406408, -0.0000272051, -5.68232*10^-10, 0.26728} *)
```

Given the values of `b, c, d`, `g` is just a number. Perhaps by plot you mean a [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) of its values.

```
Histogram[g]
```

[image]